# Radius Border for Background Image Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have some question, is it possible to create background image with rounded border? I have a `Card` widget, and I want to put an image as a background. Because i put a radius border on `Card`, background image is overflowing because its not affected by radius border. Thank you.

```
                    Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.dstATop),
                                image: new AssetImage("assets/images/dummy_card.jpg")
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Column()
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your container in a [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code

```
ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.dstATop),
                                image: new AssetImage("assets/images/dummy_card.jpg")
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Column()
                        ),
),
```